# Applying mask for coloured image in Open cv

Tags: python, opencv

What changes should I make in below code so that if I know HSV value of green colour, I should get image segments which don't contain the green colour as my output?

Image on which I was working is: [source image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QhWM9EBywtdM33n0ijm2U4QUgbKxB-F0)

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("sun.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))         ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)

imask = mask>0      ## slice the green
green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

cv2.imshow('image ',green)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite("green1.png", green)     ##saving
```

actual output: is the only green coloured portion
expected output: except the green colour portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the line

```
green[imask] = img[imask]
```

with

```
green = img[!imask] # not of mask to get non-green regions in image
```